# Akka: testing supervision strategy with TestProbes

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, akka-testkit, akka-supervision

I'm testing an actor which spawns and coordinates child worker actors. In order to do so I've substituted child actor creation with `TestProbe`s which are used to observe and simulate exchanged messages.

However I've ran into a problem when trying to test actor's supervision strategy. I was able to simulate an exception generated within child actor by setting up an `AutoPilot` on a `TestProbe`. But it turned out that `TestProbe`s are supervised  by system guardian by default and my test actor does not receive error notifications.

One idea that came into mind is to set up an intermediate `ForwarderActor`s layer that will be supervised by test actor and generate test exception, but otherwise forward messages between `TestProbe` and test actor, like this:

```
case class GenerateException(exception: Exception)

class ForwarderActor(phase: Phase) extends Actor {
  val probe  = TestProbe(phase.toString)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GenerateException(e) => throw e
    case msg if sender() == probe.ref => context.parent ! msg
    case msg => probe.ref ! msg
  }
}
```

This way actor will supervised properly but messages can still be inspected with `TestProbe`s.

I wonder if there is an easier way of accomplishing this?